# Puppet: Class b required by class A in site.pp

Tags: class, parameter-passing, puppet

I  have 2 modules with class name has A-Class and B-Class. I want to make sure B-Class runs first and with A-Class when i run Puppet apply site.pp. But getting error as 'Syntax error at 'mongos'; expected '}' at require B-Class line, below is the code.

```
node 'HOST-1'{
    class { 'a_class':
            require b_class,
            first => "abcd",
            log_data_path => "/log/serv.1",
        }

    class { 'b_Class':
            build_id => "php_2.4",
        }
}
```

Is it the right way to use require? Else what is the better way to do.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also right. But better way to do it is

```
class { 'a_class':
        first => "abcd",
        log_data_path => "/log/serv.1",
        require => Class['a_class']
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost right, but `require` is a parameter in its own right.

```
require => Class['a_class']
```

In this scenario, you could also use chaining arrows.

```
class { 'b_class': ... }
->
class { 'a_class': ... }
```

This will have the same effect.